# Some way to outline labeled regions separately?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have processed an image to the point where I have certain labelled regions. Shown here with each labelled region in different shade.

[image]

I would like to show the outline of each region separately. Currently I am using `bwmorph(labeledImage,'remove')` but this treats any regions contacting each other and keeps the outlines of the conjunction of the multiple regions.

[image]

I am looking for a function that will keep all the outline / edge pixels for each region, something that would result in an image like the following (green edges added to show what is missing from the method I am already using).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate all regions, so why dont you treat them separatly?
See this [bwboundaries](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/visboundaries.html#bundmen-2).